# How do I get glBindTextureUnit() to work?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-4

The following works fine:

```cpp
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_ID);
```

But when I replace it with this, it doesn't work. (I don't get any errors, just a black color instead of the texture):

```cpp
glBindTextureUnit(GL_TEXTURE0, m_ID);
```

From what I searched online I can't see what I'm doing wrong, so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: You should use [debug output when doing OpenGL development so that you get OpenGL Errors when they happen](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glBindTextureUnit` does not take OpenGL texture unit enumerators like `GL_TEXTURE0`. It takes texture unit *indices*, like `0`.